# Can electric field and force be in opposite directions?

Tags: forces, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

If electric field is what is applying the force then how can they be in different directions? Eg: -q has an electric field inwards but it exerts force outwards on another charge -q1......  Doesn't make sense how they can be in opposite direction....

Answer (score 0):

Electric field is defined to be the force applied on a test charge of an unit positive charge by the source charge. As the test charge in the definition is always positive the direction of the electric field depends only upon the charge of the source charge. 
    In case of evaluating the force on any charge we just multiply ( for the simplest case of discrete point charge) the electric field at that point by the charge with its sign of the test charge. That is how electric field and coupons force can have opposite direction. 
    I hope it now makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Yes electric field and electric force in a charge can be in different diection. Suppose there is +q charge in static situation the elctric field in entire space around +ve charge will be in outward direction. And if you place +ve test charge in the field than force on this  charge will be in direction of force but if you place - ve test charge in the field made by +q than the force will be toward the +charge

Answer (score 0):

We define,  $ \vec{\text{F}} = q\vec{E} $.

If $q>0$ the force $F$ is *parallel* to the field $E$. I.e. a +ve charge in the field will experience a force in the direction of the field.

If $q<0$ the force $F$ is *anti-parallel* to the field $E$. I.e. a -ve charge in the field will experience a force in the opposite direction of the field.

Found the same answer (better) explained here. :/   [Confusion regarding the direction of an electric field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/355424/confusion-regarding-the-direction-of-an-electric-field?rq=1)